# Remove separation line between first cell and navigation bar in plain table view in IOS

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

I have `UITableView` and am displaying data in it using custom `UITableViewCell`. My problem is - I need to remove `separation line` between `navigation bar` and `first cell` of `plain table view` as i have mentioned in my attached image.

[image]

here is my code :

```
   UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];
   separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:229/255.0 green:229/255.0 blue:229/255.0 alpha:1.0];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

Can you give me any idea how to remove this line? Thanks

Comment: Could you add your separator lines to the bottom of the cells instead of the top?

Answer (score 0):

In your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` add this line :

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, cell.bounds.size.width);
}
```

Comment: I have added this, but it's not working (getting same output), thanks @ali59a..!